# CSS attribute selector not working when the attribute is applied using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

```
.variations_button[style*="display: none;"] + div
```

This is my CSS selector which works fine if the style attribute is already in the DOM on page load:

http://jsfiddle.net/xn3y3hu0/

However, if i hide the .variations_button div using javascript, the selector is not working anymore:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.variations_button').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/55seee1r/

Any idea whats wrong? Looks like the CSS is not refreshing, because if i edit another property using the inspector, the color changes red instantly.

Comment: Is the space-character present when JavaScript adds the style?

Comment: if it were my code I'd show/hide the element with a class, and use the class in the selector.

Comment: Of course i tried with the space character. And yes, a class hide/show would be easier, but this is for a WordPress plugin and i don't want to overwrite the core code.

Comment: Make sure to check the second jsfiddle link, just edited the question, because i pasted the wrong link there.

Comment: Might be obvious to some, but CSS atrribute selectors ONLY work on inline CSS (i e. this is what the style property returns, CSS atrribute selectors don't work with CSS set by other stylesheets (that is computed CSS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the selector you use, `[style*="display: none;"]`, is looking for the presence of the *exact string* of `"display: none;"` in the `style` attribute, it requires the browser's JavaScript engine inserts that precise string, including the white-space character (incidentally in Chrome 39/Windows 8.1 it does). For your particular browser you may need to remove the space, and to target most<sup>1</sup> browsers, use both versions of the attribute-value string, giving:

```
.variations_button[style*="display: none;"] + div,
.variations_button[style*="display:none;"] + div
```

```css
.variations_button[style*="display: none;"]+div,
.variations_button[style*="display:none;"]+div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="variations_button" style="display: none;">asd</div>
<div>test</div>
```

Of course, it remains much simpler to use classes to hide an element, toggling that class with JavaScript, and using the class as part of the CSS selector, for example:

```js
$('.variations_button + div').on('click', function() {
  $('.variations_button').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.hidden + div {
  color: red;
}
.variations_button + div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variations_button">asd</div>
<div>test</div>
```

As I understand it, the problem of the above not working once jQuery is involved, is because jQuery's `hide()`,`show()` and `toggle()` methods *seem to* update the `display` property of the element's `style` property, rather than setting the attribute directly. The updated attribute-value (as represented in the `style` attribute) seems to be a representation of the `style` property (derived, presumably, from its `cssText`). Because the attribute is unchanged, and merely serves as a representation of a property, the CSS attribute-selectors don't, or perhaps *can't*, match.

That said, a somewhat clunky workaround is to directly set the attribute; in the following demo this uses jQuery's `attr()` method (though the native DOM `node.setAttribute()` would work equally well):

```
  $(document).click(function() {
    // setting the style attribute of the selected element(s),
    // using the attr() method, and the available anonymous function:
    $('.variations_button').attr('style', function(i, style) {
      // i: the index of the current element from the collection,
      // style: the current value (before manipulation) of the attribute.

      // caching the cssText of the node's style object:
      var css = this.style.cssText;

      // if the string 'display' is not found in the cssText:
      if (css.indexOf('display') === -1) {
        // we return the current text plus the appended 'display: none;' string:
        return css + 'display: none;';
      // otherwise:
      } else {
        // we replace the string starting with 'display:', followed by an
        // optional white-space ('\s?'), followed by a matching string of
        // one or more alphabetic characters (grouping that last string,
        // parentheses):
        return css.replace(/display:\s?([a-z]+)/i, function(a, b) {
          // using the anonymous function available to 'replace()',
          // a: the complete match, b: the grouped match (a-z),
          // if b is equal to none we return 'display: block', otherwise
          // we return 'display: none':
          return 'display: ' + (b === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.variations_button').attr('style', function(i, style) {
      var css = this.style.cssText;
      if (css.indexOf('display') === -1) {
        return css + 'display: none;';
      } else {
        return css.replace(/display:\s?([a-z]+)/i, function(a, b) {
          return 'display: ' + (b === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.variations_button[style*="display: none;"]+div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variations_button">asd</div>
<div>test</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Substring Matching Attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).
- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).
  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Sure, i tested with space and without space. As i mentioned in my question, it works without the javascript part. But once the style attribute is added using javascript, it fails to run. Even your example. And sure, toggleClass would be easier, but this is for a WordPress plugin and i don't want to overwrite the core code.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour with a demo? Because it seems that something (but I don't know, and can't see, what) is being left not.

Comment: Jeez, sorry, i inserted the wrong link in my question. Check out the second jsfiddle:)